# How To Locate First Element In An Array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to fetch the first element in a row and print it. How do I do that?

For example, Array A has:

```
([[   0, 435, 500, 432, 658]])
```

I need to print 0. How will I be able to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It is an example of a 2D array with only 1 row, hence you can use the following [0,0]

The first 0 will select the first row or the 1D array and the second 0 will select the first element in that array.
More about indexing numpy array can be found here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html

```
arr=np.array([[   0, 435, 500, 432, 658]])
#To get the first element from the array inside the first array, you should do
print(arr[0,0])
```

Comment: Just to clarify - if you were using a list of a similar structure, you would index as: `[[0, 435, 500, 432, 658]][0][0]`

Comment: @Recessive yes but in this case it's an numpy array!

Comment: I know, just thought I'd add in case someone was using normal lists and stumbled on this question